# cascading autocomplete with jquery and bootstrap

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete

I have problem in bootstrap autocomplete function. i want the cascading type function like family come with his relative Common Name.i want to use textbox not the select box. i have two input box with id #family and specicies. when i press the key on the family text box the autocomplete function run and show the famlies name.then i want the show those comanam name which come under the
selected family name.

```
 jQuery("#family").autocomplete
 ({
 source: "<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory')."/ajax_familytype.php"; ?>",
minLength: 1,
select: function (event, ui) 
{
var label = ui.item.label;
    var value = ui.item.value;
    var dataString = 'action=familytype&family_name='+value;
    jQuery.ajax({type: "POST",
                 url: "<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory')."/ajax_family.php"; ?>",
                 data: dataString,
                 cache: false,
                 success: function(html){  alert(html);
                        if(html!=''){
                            var res = html.split("==");
                            jQuery('#species').addClass("commanclass");
                             jQuery(".commanclass").autocomplete({
                                    source: [html],
                                    minLength: 1,
                            });
                        }
                    } 
                });
            }
        });
```

family.php

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=='familytype')
  {` $family_name=$_POST['family_name'];
     global $wpdb;
     $familyid=$wpdb->get_row("SELECT Bird_Family_ID from obc_birdfamily   where Bird_Family_Name='".$family_name."'"); 
     $family_id=$familyid->Bird_Family_ID;
     $commannames_arr = array();
     $commannames_html = "";
     $commannames = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM obc_birdinfo where Bird_Family_ID = '".$family_id."'"); if (isset($commannames) && sizeof($commannames) > 0) {
    foreach ($commannames as $commanname) {
        $commannames_arr[] = '"' . trim($commanname->Bird_Common_Name) . '"';
    }
    $commannames_html.=implode(",", $commannames_arr);
      "[".$commannames_html."]";
      echo $commannames_arr;

}exit;
}
```

Comment: can you post your html code?

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" id="family" name="family" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['family'])){ echo $_GET['family']; } ?>">
     
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="species" id="species" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['species'])){ echo $_GET['species']; } ?>">